# Magento display a 3rd price on the product page

Tags: magento

I would like to add a third price to my products like "MSRP" on the latest version but not available on mine (Magento 1.4.1.1).
I would like to display it on the product page and it has to change according to the selected option.

So, I started by creating a new attribute called "msrp".
I managed to get it for every child product on my **view.phtml** file with the following code:

```
<?php
if($_product->isConfigurable())
{
      $_associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
       foreach($_associatedProducts as $assProducts)
      {  
$msrp = $assProducts->getData("msrp");
echo "MSRP: ".$msrp."<br />" ;
}
}
?>
```

Now the question is how to show it only one at a time and which corresponds to the selected option?
(Just like the normal price changes when we select an option.)

Maybe with a piece of javascript in this file?
**/app/design/frontend/[...]/[...]/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: This will require you to override `getJsonConfig` in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable` to include your custom MSRP price. Not only that, but you'll probably have to rewrite some functionality in `/js/varien/configurable.js` - good luck.

Comment: It seems that it's more complicated than I expected... I've just had a look to the getJsonConfig function and I don't know how to add my MSRP attribut into it. I don't even know how to recover it after in my catalog/product/view.phtml template... Never mind, thanks for your answer anyway.